# Python sns heatmap KeyError: Interval(6.3, 8.4, closed='right')

Tags: python, heatmap

Hey I am tryin to do this exercise for my assignment:

Task 6. Visualize the relationship between air compounds and the weather factor

To compare the concentrations of the compounds to the measurements of the weather factor without taking into account the time dimension, create a scatterplot and a heatmap for each compound separately with the weather factor on the horizontal axis (so 2 scatterplots and 2 heatmaps in total). For the heatmap, you should create appropriate bins for the data for which this is necessary (using for instance the pd.cut method).

Discuss which visualization, the scatter plot or the heatmap, is better suited for this comparison in the variable observations_scatterplot_vs_heatmap.

Here is my code:

```
#// BEGIN_TODO [EDA_relationship] (5 points)
sns.scatterplot(x=df_data[chosen_weather_factor], y=df_data[compound1])
plt.xlabel('Wind speed')
plt.ylabel(compound1)
plt.show()

sns.scatterplot(x=df_data[chosen_weather_factor], y=df_data[compound2])
plt.xlabel('Wind speed')
plt.ylabel(compound2)
plt.show()

bins = pd.cut(df_data[chosen_weather_factor], 10)
grouped_data = df_data.groupby(bins)[compound1].mean().reset_index()
heatmap_data = grouped_data.pivot(index='wind_speed', columns=bins, values=compound1)
sns.heatmap(heatmap_data, cmap='YlOrRd')
plt.xlabel(chosen_weather_factor)
plt.ylabel(compound1)
plt.title(f"Heatmap for {compound1} with respect to {chosen_weather_factor}")
plt.show()

bins = pd.cut(df_data[chosen_weather_factor], 10)
heatmap_data = df_data.groupby([bins])[compound2].mean().reset_index()
heatmap_data = heatmap_data.pivot(index='wind_speed', columns=bins, values=compound2)
sns.heatmap(heatmap_data, cmap='YlOrRd')
plt.xlabel('Wind speed')
plt.ylabel(compound2)
plt.show()
```

And this is the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: Interval(6.3, 8.4, closed='right')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-11233484bf6a> in <module>
     12 bins = pd.cut(df_data[chosen_weather_factor], 10)
     13 grouped_data = df_data.groupby(bins)[compound1].mean().reset_index()
---> 14 heatmap_data = grouped_data.pivot(index='wind_speed', columns=bins, values=compound1)
     15 sns.heatmap(heatmap_data, cmap='YlOrRd')
     16 plt.xlabel(chosen_weather_factor)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
   6877         from pandas.core.reshape.pivot import pivot
   6878 
-> 6879         return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
   6880 
   6881     _shared_docs[

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py in pivot(data, index, columns, values)
    447             index = [data[idx] for idx in index]
    448 
--> 449         data_columns = [data[col] for col in columns]
    450         index.extend(data_columns)
    451         index = MultiIndex.from_arrays(index)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    447             index = [data[idx] for idx in index]
    448 
--> 449         data_columns = [data[col] for col in columns]
    450         index.extend(data_columns)
    451         index = MultiIndex.from_arrays(index)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3025             if is_integer(indexer):
   3026                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: Interval(6.3, 8.4, closed='right')
```

Anyone know how to solve this error?

I tried using different bin methods

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates a `KeyError` in this line:

`heatmap_data = grouped_data.pivot(index='wind_speed', columns=bins, values=compound1)`

Difficult to understand what's going on without the data.. But I think you might not be able to use `bins` as arg for `columns` here (because the bins are not columns, you get a KeyError)?

**Edit:**
This replicates the error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val_1': np.random.randn(200), 'val_2': np.random.randn(200)})
bins = pd.cut(df['val_1'], 10)
grouped_data = df.groupby(bins)['val_2'].mean().reset_index()
heatmap_data = grouped_data.pivot(columns=bins, values='val_2')
```

While if `columns=bins` is replaced by an actual column name there is no error, e.g. `columns='val_1'`

Comment: Thats not the problem since you are pivoting the df

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? 
What I meant is: the KeyError occurs because the bins are not columns, therefore you can't specify those as such in the `pivot` function. I've added an example in my original post that replicates this.
I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, so I can't recommend an alternative, just point out why the error occurs. hope that helps

Comment: Can you explain with what you mean by "bins are not columns"?. With what I know the column argument has to be either a single value or a list.

Comment: I mean; the variable `bins` contains objects that are not column names. Check by `np.isin(bins, list(grouped_data.columns))`, which will tell for every element in `bins` whether is a column name. 
For `pd.pivot()`, the `columns` argument takes `str` or `list of str`, which must be existing column names: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html